# Xamarin screen orientaton not working on Nexus 9 emulator

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

How can I force the screen orientation to landscape on the Nexus 9 emulator?
I used  RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Landscape in MainActivity.cs and it works well on all other emulators
The problems show up only on Nexus 9
Any solutions?

Comment: I suspect its because that is a tablet, so its natural orientation is Landscape (wide). You might need to manually rotate emulator, or test on actual device. Are you trying to rotate 90 degrees? On a tablet that *might* be FROM Landscape TO Portrait - you may need different code. A test: `RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait; Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000), () => { Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Landscape); return false;});` Does that show one orientation, then two seconeds later rotate to the other orientation?

Comment: I used RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Landscape in MainActivity.cs and it works on other emulators . I need to start the application always on landscape

Comment: I understand. It may be a bug in emulator, for all landscape devices (tablets), because it isn't a real device, isn't receiving orientation data from a gyroscope. The test code I give above is a work-around (not needed on a real device), to tell the emulator to rotate to Portrait, then back to Landscape. I believe this will trigger Xamarin to correctly orient to Landscape. At some point you'll need access to an actual tablet (any tablet), to verify that setting Landscape works there.